# Getting multiple variables from post to php

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting data from my database without reloading the page by posting to a php page.

```
function getdata() {
  $.post( "somepath/getdata.php", function(o) {
    var texts = o.split('&;');
    // o is respond from php script
  });
}
```

The php looks like this:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'bar';
$var2 = 'foo';
//vars come from database

echo $var1."&;".$var2;
?>
```

My problem is that I want to pass multiple variables from php without putting them into a string and seperate them by some kind of separator ( in this case `&;` ). Is it possible to pass such variables directly to jquery without echoing them ?

Comment: insert all value to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can push your return variables to an array and [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it:

```
$result = array();
$result["var1"] = 'bar';
$result["var2"] = 'foo';

echo json_encode($result);
```

This returns a string that looks like:

```
{"var1":"bar","var2":"foo"}
```

And then in JavaScript:

```
function getdata() {
    $.post( "somepath/getdata.php", function(o) {
        var data = JSON.parse(o);
        console.log(data.var1); // logs "bar"
        console.log(data.var2); // logs "foo"
    });
}
```

The result is returned as a string, so first we need to parse it into a JSON object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). You can then access the values using the key name as set in PHP